# How to draw "age-gender" style column chart with Google Chart Tools?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

[image]

I can draw a side-by-side style column chart, and a stacked chart (all above x-axis), but not this one. How to make the value below x-axis still positive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Column chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart), set the `isStacked` property to true and multiply one gender's value (female in your example) by -1 this will give you the bars you are looking for.  next you need to alter the vAxis format to hide the negative symbol.  There are some limitations to Google Charts that will make 100% of this request harder to achieve.  The biggest one is that Google Charts only supports part of the [ICU pattern set](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html#_details), and that means you can't add the percent modifier to both the positive and negative values.  To address this I've multiplied the percent value by 100 instead of fractions of 1.0 which would be technically correct.  Also as you have pointed out the tooltips show negative values.  to address this you need to give a formatted value for the Female datums that is the positive value (maybe you can include the % in that case, because it's just a string and isn't the charted value).

In the [Google Code Playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#column_chart) try this:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  /* Create and populate the data table. */
  var data = {
    "cols":[
      {"id":"Age","label":"Age","type":"string"},
      {"id":"Female","label":"Female","type":"number"},
      {"id":"Male","label":"Male","type":"number"}
    ],"rows":[
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":13,"f":"13-17"},
          {"v":-11,"f":"11%"},
          {"v":2,"f":"2%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":18,"f":"18-24"},
          {"v":-8,"f":"8%"},
          {"v":5,"f":"5%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":25,"f":"25-34"},
          {"v":-6,"f":"6%"},
          {"v":8,"f":"8%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":35,"f":"35-44"},
          {"v":-6,"f":"6%"},
          {"v":10,"f":"10%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":45,"f":"45-54"},
          {"v":-8,"f":"8%"},
          {"v":12,"f":"12%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":55,"f":"55-64"},
          {"v":-3,"f":"3%"},
          {"v":7,"f":"7%"}]
      },
      {
        "c":[
          {"v":64,"f":"64+"},
          {"v":-1,"f":"1%"},
          {"v":2,"f":"2%"}]
      }
    ]
  };

  /* Create and draw the visualization. */
  new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'))
    .draw(new google.visualization.DataTable(data), {
      title:"Coffee Consumption by age",
      isStacked: true,
      vAxis: {
        format: "##;##"
      },
      width:600, height:400,
      hAxis: {
        title: "Age"
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image: Stacked Chart]

Comment: But you actually change the value. When you move the mouse on the bar below x-axis, it shows negative but actually it should be positive.

Comment: That can be addressed as well by setting a format for the value

Comment: Make sense. Do you know how to hide the "-" mark? And another problem is that when I use stacked chart, the order of legend is reversed. How to fix it?

Comment: I've worked out how to hide the `-` but it comes at the cost of dropping the `%` (blame Google's partial implementation of String.Format).  As for the order in this case arrayToDataTable is taking the columns in reverse order (don't know why) but I can say it isn't derived from their values so put them in the opposite order you want the legend to appear

Comment: fixed the code comments so you can past it into the Google Playgorund (their auto code formatter was making the // comment out everything

Comment: Getting closer. Do you know how to reverse the legend order? And another question, how can I set interval of `vAxis.gridlines` (10, 20, 30, ...) instead of setting a count (now my chart shows 11, 22, 33)?

Comment: Fixed the order, and the tooltips

Comment: No "%" no problem. Do you know how can I adjust the baseline so that it is always in the middle?

Comment: Your min and max values for the `vAxis` need to be equal, try adding this to the `vAxis` option: `viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow: {min: -100, max: 100}`